# How to join 4 tables with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry, now here is the code, basically, the first query returns me a tab which contains fk_id_produto, i wanted to join it with thee second one with the id_pedido

```
(SELECT fk_id_produto,fk_id_pedido, descricao_produto, valor_produto 
FROM Pedido_Produto
INNER JOIN Produto ON pedido_produto.fk_id_produto = produto.id_produto);

INNER JOIN ON

(SELECT id_cliente,nome_cliente,id_pedido,valor_pedido,data_do_pedido A
FROM Cliente 
INNER JOIN Pedido ON cliente.id_cliente = pedido.fk_id_cliente);
```

[image: Result of the first part of the query]

[image: Result of the second part of the query]

Comment: When you're asking for help, you’ll get more/better answers if you don’t post screenshots or photos. Cut & paste the text directly into the message.

Why?
1. It's easier for people to read it.
2. It allows those reading it to cut & paste the text, making it easier to work on solving your problem.
3. It makes it searchable, so that someone can find this thread when Googling for information in the future.
4. A screen reader can't read a picture which limits access to some in our community.

Comment: Sorry, i'm a noob with stack overflow, i changed it to show the code instead of images

Comment: Good. Now do the same for the query results.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do a join with the two selects that you have

```
SELECT * 
FROM
   (SELECT 1) as s1 inner join
   (SELECT 2) as s2 on s1.id_pedido = s1.fk_id_pedido
```

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        fk_id_produto,
        fk_id_pedido, 
        descricao_produto, 
        valor_produto 
    FROM 
        Pedido_Produto 
        INNER JOIN Produto 
            ON pedido_produto.fk_id_produto = produto.id_produto
     ) as s1 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        id_cliente,
        nome_cliente,
        id_pedido,
        valor_pedido,
        data_do_pedido A
    FROM 
        Cliente 
        INNER JOIN  Pedido
            ON cliente.id_cliente = pedido.fk_id_cliente
    ) as s2 
    ON s1.id_pedido = s1.fk_id_pedido
```

BR

Answer (score 1):

So you have four tables:

- Products (P)
- Clients (C)
- Orders  (O)
- OrderProducts (OP)

```
SELECT
           *
FROM
           OP
  JOIN
           P ON P.ID = OP.P_ID
  JOIN
           O ON O.ID = OP.O_ID
  JOIN
           C ON C.ID = O.C_ID
```

That will produce one row for each OP and give you the product, order and client details